OIDC Linkedin authentication canceled in django applicaation
I have integrated OIDC Linkedin third party auth in my django application and it automatically cancled authenticaton. I'm  attaching logs for refrence, if anyone faced this issue before or does anyone know the solution please feel free to give me soluction,
logs
Django version is 4.1.2
library i used
social-auth-core: 4.5.4

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
